# SQL join avoid cartesian product

Tags: sql-server

Trying to avoid a cartesian product using the below tables

```
#t1 (1,'2019-03-01','TN',0.33)
    (2,'2019-03-01','TN',0.13)
    (3,'2019-03-01','TN',0.63)

#t2 ('2019-03-01','TN',3.1)
#t2 ('2019-03-01','TN',4.1)
#t2 ('2019-03-01','TN',5.1)

select * from #t1
select * from #t2

select a.cd,a.loc,(a.sales*b.multi)
from #t2 a join #t1 b on a.cd=b.cd and a.loc=b.loc
```

This understandbly returns a cartesian product :

```
2019-03-01  TN  1.023
2019-03-01  TN  1.353
2019-03-01  TN  1.683
2019-03-01  TN  0.403
2019-03-01  TN  0.533
2019-03-01  TN  0.663
2019-03-01  TN  1.953
2019-03-01  TN  2.583
2019-03-01  TN  3.213
```

How can i write the query to return a single row result set with Table B as the driver?

Expected Output:

```
1  2019-03-01 TN (0.33*3.1) -- value of
2  2019-03-01 TN (0.13*4.1) 
3  2019-03-01 TN (0.63*5.1)
```

Comment: It looks like the records actually relate to the order they exist in the table. Add an identity column to table B and join on that.

Comment: Column names on you source data would be helpful? Is there a value in #t2 that corresponds to the first column (e.g. 1, 2, 3) in the #t1? How do you know you want to multiply the sales value from the first row of #t1 with the multi value from the first row in #t2?

Comment: Table rows do not have a inherent order, what would you expect to happen if t2 had four rows that matched the three rows in t1?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t1 table(id int, cd date, loc varchar(2), sales money);
insert into @t1(id, cd,loc, sales)
values
--#t1 
(1,'2019-03-01','TN',0.33),
(2,'2019-03-01','TN',0.13),
(3,'2019-03-01','TN',0.63);


declare @t2 table(cd date, loc varchar(2), multi decimal(5, 2));
insert into @t2(cd, loc, multi) 
values
('2019-03-01','TN',3.1),
('2019-03-01','TN',4.1),
('2019-03-01','TN',5.1)

select *
from 
(
    --this is better...than using t1 directly, especially if other locs are there (they wont have id starting from 1, 2, 3)
    select *, row_number() over(partition by cd, loc order by id) as rownum
    from @t1 
) as t1
join
(
    select *, row_number() over(partition by cd, loc order by multi) as rownum --lowest multi gets 1, next gets 2 and so on
    from @t2
) as t2 on t1.cd = t2.cd and t1.loc = t2.loc and t1.rownum = t2.rownum;
```